# How to Convert Db value to nested JSON value using Java

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, java-8

```
JSONDATA:

{
  "Channel": {
    "SalesChaneel": {
      " Step1:salesChannel": {
        "ChannelList1": {
          "Lis1": "Vlaue1",
          "Lis2": "Vlaue1",
          "Lis3": "Vlaue1"
        },
        "ChannelList2": {
          "Lis4": "Vlaue2",
          "Lis5": "Vlaue2",
          "Lis6": "Vlaue2"
        }
      }
    },
    "SalesChanee2": {
      " Step2:salesChannel": {
        "ChannelList3": {
          "Lis8": "Vlaue1",
          "Lis9": "Vlaue1",
          "Lis10": "Vlaue1"
        },
        "ChannelList4": {
          "Lis11": "Vlaue2",
          "Lis12": "Vlaue2",
          "Lis13": "Vlaue2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

---------------------
```

Hi, I need to  form  the above json formatted values using the below db value.Attached Screen shot.I am getting the values using select Query .Can anyone Please give me the logic to form the Json Using the values which i get from DB.I am trying to use Java to write the program.

My db coloums looks Below:

[image]

Comment: This is not related to typescript, you need to generate the json at the server side.

Comment: Hi naladri . I need the logic to generate JSON format . I can able to pass object from database to type script and able to form JSON.

Comment: Mainly I need json to display  as  a tree view using angular material

Comment: your question is in complete. kindly add the code which is used to read the data from database.

Comment: And once the data is obtained, it is pojo format right ?.

Comment: hi @Sree :i am using java jdbc and its pojo only.anyway i found the logic